# updating million rows based on resultset from previous query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update a table consisting of million rows

there are two tables table1 and table2

```
SELECT ID
FROM (
select ID from table1 where<condition>
) as result1
INNER JOIN table2 ON result1.field=table2.field 
GROUPBY table2.field 
HAVING <condtion>
```

and on this @resultset1 ID, I have to update table 1

```
UPDATE table1
SET x=true
where ID EXISTS IN (@resultset1)
```

there are millions of rows in both table. how do i do it?

And Can anyone say whats wrong with this, i am trying some alternative over join

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET x=true
WHERE <condition> AND EXISTS(
    SELECT* FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM table2 t2
        WHERE t2.field =  t1.field 
    ) AS result 
WHERE<condition on resultset field>
);
```

Comment: scale doesn't matter, what does matter though is the statement to update the data.

Comment: what is the best way to minimize time to do the 1st query and update table1?

Comment: you could start through grabbing the data, doing the manipulation, then putting the data back.  Go to bed, and let the program run until you go to bed tomorrow.  ...finally you're done.  That's what I'd do.

Comment: Why not put the result of the first query into a temp table?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you simply do like below. Though I don't really see a need of `group by` and `having` provided if this is your actual query.

```
UPDATE table1
SET x=true
where ID IN (
SELECT ID
FROM (
select ID from table1 where<condition>
) as result1
INNER JOIN table2 ON result1.field=table2.field 
GROUPBY table2.field 
HAVING <condtion>
)
```

Another good option would be `JOIN` both result set and do the `UPDATE` like

```
UPDATE table1 t1
JOIN 
(
SELECT ID
FROM (
select ID from table1 where<condition>
) as result1
INNER JOIN table2 ON result1.field=table2.field 
GROUPBY table2.field 
HAVING <condtion>
) X ON t1.ID = X.ID
SET t1.x=true
```

**EDIT:**

You can as well store the result of fist query in a temporary table (As already suggested by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name)) and then do the UPDATE using a JOIN with the temporary table. Somethig like below

```
create temporary table idtemp(ID INT);

insert into idtemp
SELECT ID
FROM (
select ID from table1 where<condition>
) result1
INNER JOIN table2 ON result1.field=table2.field 
GROUPBY table2.field 
HAVING <condtion>
```

Finally do the update like

```
UPDATE table1 t1
JOIN idtemp it ON t1.ID = it.ID
SET t1.x=true
```

Comment: yeah but the issue is the tables contain million rows, executing such query will hang upthe server

Comment: @user2368055, have you tried both version of query as in my answer? Anyways, check edited answer (mainly the `EDIT:` part).

Comment: is there any alternative to join?

Comment: @user2368055, You can use a subquery to get all the id's in temp table but JOIN would be much eficient. Why don't you give a try?

Comment: I have tried and join works, but its taking a lot of time, as i have million rows and i think join is expensive enough. the system hangs. see i have edited the problem and mentioned an alternative but dont know whats wrong with that, it givs me error

Comment: try subquery version like `UPDATE table1 SET x=true where ID in (select Id from idtemp)`

Comment: how does this work, i couldnt get any explanation to this. does the update runs only for the rows whos id is in " IDs in (select Id from idtemp)" or it runs for every rows and verifies the condition thereafter taking a lot of time?

Comment: It updates only the rows where ID is in the list. Consider learning SQL for better undersanding.

Answer (score 0):

1. Output the results of the first query to a file.
2. Convert the output to update statements, one update per id (using sed or whatever)
3. Split the statements into separate files, maybe a 1000 per file (using split or whatever)
4. Run each file as an sql script with a pause (eg 10 seconds) between each execution (to allow logs to update etc and spread the load), using a simple runner script the loops over the files